# iOS Restkit and Etag

Tags: ios, restkit, afnetworking, restkit-0.20, etag

Any of you Restkit users that are utilizing Etags, how are you detecting 304 response?  I am seeing that NSURLConnection will send off the "if-none-match" in the header, but it won't return a 304, instead it seems to sort of internally detect the 304, but then in the response, it just returns a 200.

Comment: I guess this is actually handled by AFNetworking to return a cached result...